# Debugging pop up window "Missing Manifest?"

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-manifest, xamarin

Im getting this error message. I created a new project and hit debug to test it. I added nothing and i get this pop up message. what could be my issue? I can create a new blank project wtih out the Controllers and Models projects in them it debugs just fine. But i need to use this solution provided to me.

New to mono droid any help will be apreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue could be that none of the projects have been set to be deployed to a device.

Right click your `Solution > Properties > Configuration Properties > Tick The Deploy checkbox` for your Application Project if not already.

Also make sure to mark one of your activities with `MainLauncher = true`, otherwise Android does not know which Activity to start first. This is done in the `[Activity()]` attribute like so:

```
[Activity(Label = "Epic Activity", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity {}
```

Answer (score 0):

> what could be my issue?

You are using Visual Studio... Android plays much nicer with Eclipse.

Kidding aside, every Android application requires an [`AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file. It looks like you are using MonoDroid, and there are [docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml) about creating the manifest file.

Also, make sure you have built the project.

> AndroidManifest.xml is generated as part of the build process, and the XML found within Properties\AndroidManifest.xml is merged with XML generated based on custom attributes.